# How safe is an edited file?

Tags: security, data-recovery

I didn't find any questions regarding this at all...

but I was wondering: Is there a way for an attacker to rebuild information that was saved in a file at any earlier time?

Possible Scenario: Person A lends his Laptop to a friend. Instead of just deleting his importantpasswords.txt, he just opens it and overwrites his old passwords with new (fake) ones.

Is there any way for anyone to recover the original passwords? are there differences between filesystems, file types, OSes?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Simply editing a file is no guarantee against any kind of in depth or forensic analysis and depends on every piece of software in the chain. A text editor can save multiple backups of a file, or for safety have a process that goes "save file as new name, delete old file, then rename new file to old file" which protects against data loss. The filesystem driver could do the same. The operating system could also do automated backups of your data and store it elsewhere. There is no one single answer to this question and there are a whole raft of programs, problems and implications.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the file system (and thus on the OS). For example, UFS (Solaris/BSD) would overwrite the existing blocks on disk, and allocate more if necessary. ZFS, having a copy-on-write paradigm, would allocate new blocks and once the file was written, put the old blocks on the "free list".

Of course, when using ZFS it would be possible to reconstruct the data (if you knew what you were looking for).

There are also file systems that actually keep old version of files. NTFS can do this for example. It would be very obvious to recover the old version of the file then.

<sub>About the example case: you should never store passwords unencrypted on a disk, and if you hand over the system to someone else, do a secure wipe. Also, on laptops it's always a good idea to use filesystem or full disk encryption.</sub>

Comment: More filesystems are vulnerable if the editor acts like this: [*Why would `vim` create a new file every time you save a file?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26093425)

Comment: This is assuming you're using a hard drive where "sector N" is always "sector N", not an ssd where "sector N" could be mapped to "sector XYZ" the next time it's written (or do hard drives silently remap sectors too?)